# how to insert date into MySQL from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I can't insert date(even my whole form) to mySQL. Here's my code:

```
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
{
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','e-Laundrydb');
    $tglPickup = $_POST['tglPickup'];
    $barang = $_POST['inputItems'];
    $waktuPickup = $_POST['waktuPickup'];

    $query_order = "INSERT INTO order(Barang,Tanggal_Pengambilan,Waktu_Pengambilan) VALUES('$barang','$tglPickup','$waktuPickup');";

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query_order);

    if($result == false)
    {
        echo "<script>alert('INSERT IS NOT SUCCESS');</script>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script>alert('INSERT SUCCESS');</script>";
    }
}
```

I use `input type="date"` in my php. And here's my table in database:
[Table Order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7GlV.png)

I can't find where's the problem.
i updated the code and follow like your suggestions but still get nothing :(
here's the code again:

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
{
    //include('config/koneksi.php');
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','e-laundryDB');
    //INSERT KE TABLE ORDER
    $tglPickup = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($_POST['tglPickup']));
    $barang = $_POST['inputItems'];
    $waktuPickup = $_POST['waktuPickup'];

    $query_order = "INSERT INTO 'order'(Barang,Tanggal_Pengambilan,Waktu_Pengambilan) VALUES('$barang','$tglPickup','$waktuPickup')";

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query_order);

    if($result == false)
    {
        echo "<script>alert('INSERT IS NOT SUCCESS');</script>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script>alert('INSERT SUCCESS');</script>";
    }           



mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Comment: what is the date value that goes in? if you have created the table with date function it will not take time in it

Comment: sorry, i tried to specified my question. here i edited it now, thanks.

Comment: is your problem that the whole form values are not being inserted? or is it that only date is not inserted?

Comment: what is the value you are getting in `$tglPickup`

Comment: First enable errors and share the error message you get. Second, you are using mysql date field, so you will need to insert date like Y-m-d, it does not matter if you a date input field, or a text.

Comment: i think  $_POST['tglPickup'] this is your date column value, what kind of input are u getting from form????

Answer (score 3):

You have to set date format to '**`YYYY-MM-DD HH:ii:ss`**'. becasue mysql used this format for date.

Check for date format you are passing in query, there might be this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
{
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','e-Laundrydb');
    $tglPickup = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($_POST['tglPickup']));
    $barang = $_POST['inputItems'];
    $waktuPickup = $_POST['waktuPickup'];

    $query_order = "INSERT INTO order(Barang,Tanggal_Pengambilan,Waktu_Pengambilan) VALUES('$barang','$tglPickup','$waktuPickup');";

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query_order);

    if($result == false)
    {
        echo "<script>alert('INSERT IS NOT SUCCESS');</script>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script>alert('INSERT SUCCESS');</script>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well there are so many answers available related to your issue. As per your Database, your date column type is `DATE` not `DATETIME`, so you need to store values in this format:

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

**How can you get date in this format?**

```
$tglPickup = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['tglPickup']));
```

I think this column `Tanggal_Pengambilan` is your DATE column so i use it.

**Side Note:**

I am not sure, what kind of input are you getting from the `$_POST['tglPickup']`, if its proper than it will work.

Comment: Yes, tgl pickup is date column. I use <input type="date"></input>

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you'll want the the following Date format: `Y-m-d H:i:s`

You probably want to validate the format before attempting the insert query, that way if the format is invalid you can return a friendly error message to the user at this point, rather than attempting an insert and then not being easily able to decipher what went wrong.

Something like this should work:

```
function validDateFormat($date, $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s') {
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    if ($date === false) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

So you can call it like so:

```
$tglPickup = $_POST['tglPickup'];

if (validDateFormat($tglPickup)) {
    // Insert logic
} else {
    // Return a friendly error to the user
}
```

I presume the user isn't just entering the date and is selecting it so you should have full control of the format that you receive, but personally I always find programming paranoid helps :d

Hope that helps anyway.

**Edit:** As @devpro mentioned you are using `Date` and not `DateTime` so for the format, you can simply remove the `H:i:s` in the example I provided, or add a second parameter to the function call, i.e.

```
if (validDateFormat($tglPickup, 'Y-m-d')) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query_order = INSERT INTO order(Barang,Tanggal_Pengambilan,Waktu_Pengambilan) VALUES('$barang','$tglPickup','$waktuPickup')

INSERT order SET `Barang`='".$barang."',`Tanggal_Pengambilan`='".$tglPickup."',`Waktu_Pengambilan`='".$waktuPickup."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to adapt your date format to the date format in your database.
for example:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //2016-01-19 12:48:00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Convert 'd-m-Y' date format to 'Y-m-d' date format

$tglPickup=$_POST['tglPickup']; //d-m-Y

$tglPickup=explode('-',$tglPickup);

$tglPickup=$tglPickup[2]."-".$tglPickup[1]."-".$tglPickup[0]; //Y-m-d
```